Object value is changed during the request to the backend
I hope you can help me, because I couldn't find a solution to my problem. I work with Vue.js in the frontend and Laravel in the backend. When sending a POST request, the following problem occurs:
Frontend (Vue.js):
let testData = {
    comments: "test <= 5"
};
let response = await axios.post(state.updateUrl, testData);

When I send this request, the following appears in the Laravel backend (even before the validation in the FormRequest):
array:1 [ 
  "comments" => "test "
]

The character pair <= is being cut off, which is very strange as >= for example, is transferred without any problems and arrives unchanged in the backend.
What I have already checked:
Middleware: I have deactivated all middlewares to make sure that none of them are causing the problem. No middleware affects this.
Content-Type: The content type is application/json. I have also tried other content types such as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but the behaviour remains the same.
Nginx: I use Nginx as a web server and have checked the configuration. I couldn't find anything there either that could explain this behaviour.
Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong here or what the problem could be?
Many thanks in advance for your help!

Have you tried urlencoding the string?

My guess is that something is automatically applying some kind of HTML-stripper to the input to "sanitize" it.

Thank you, @MrUpsidown! With your hint I was able to work around the problem. I actually found an old package from our company that is responsible for the ‘sanitise’ function. Now I just have to figure out how to fix it. Thank you very much @Pointy. I have searched through everything again and actually found the evil of all things.
